Associated types in Lean
In Rust I can define the following traits:
trait Iterator {
    type Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}

trait Iterable {
    type Item;
    type Iterator: Iterator<Item=Self::Item>;
    fn iterator(self) -> Self::Iterator;
}

I can then define my own type CountToTen that implements the Iterable trait:
struct CountToTenIterator(u32);

impl Iterator for CountToTenIterator {
    type Item = u32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        if self.0 < 10 {
            self.0 += 1;
            Some(self.0)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

struct CountToTen;

impl Iterable for CountToTen {
    type Item = u32;
    type Iterator = CountToTenIterator;
    fn iterator(self) -> CountToTenIterator {
        CountToTenIterator(0)
    }
}

And I can use it like this:
fn print_items<I: Iterable<Item=u32>>(iterable: I) {
    let mut iterator = iterable.iterator();
    while let Some(x) = iterator.next() {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    print_items(CountToTen);
}

How can I achieve the same thing in Lean? I can define a type class Iterator like this:
class Iterator (Self : Type) where
    Item : Type
    next : Self -> Prod Self (Option Item)

and CountToTenIterator like this:
structure CountToTenIterator where
    i : UInt32

instance : Iterator CountToTenIterator where
    Item := UInt32
    next self :=
        if self.i < 10 then
            let i := self.i + 1
            ({ i }, some i)
        else
            (self, none)

but how do I define Iterable such that its member Iterator is an instance of Iterator whose Item matches the Item of the Iterable?
class Iterable (Self : Type) where
    Item : Type
    Iterator : Type -- how do I constrain this to be an instance of Iterator?
    iterator : Self -> Iterator


I figured out how to do it. The associated types have to be output parameters:
class Iterator (Self : Type) (Item : outParam Type) where
    next : Self -> Prod Self (Option Item)

class Iterable (Self : Type) (Item : outParam Type) (IterableIterator : outParam Type) [Iterator IterableIterator Item] where
    iterator : Self -> IterableIterator

structure CountToTenIterator where
    i : UInt32

instance : Iterator CountToTenIterator UInt32 where
    next self :=
        if self.i < 10 then
            let i := self.i + 1
            ({ i }, some i)
        else
            (self, none)

structure CountToTen

instance : Iterable CountToTen UInt32 CountToTenIterator where
    iterator _self := { i := 0 }

def print_items {I I2 : Type} [Iterator I2 UInt32] [Iterable I UInt32 I2] (iterable : I) : IO Unit := do
    let mut iterator := Iterable.iterator iterable
    repeat
        if let (next_iterator, some x) := Iterator.next iterator then
            println! "{x}"
            iterator := next_iterator
        else
            break

def main : IO Unit := print_items CountToTen.mk


By the way, core Lean defines the Stream class, which is equivalent to your Iterator. The design for Iterable is a bit different — it has ToStream, and the Stream.forIn function is what wants the Stream instance, and it lets you use for notation with the toStream function.

For demonstration, using the core Lean classes and notations to implement the example in eyelash's answer. I've used Stream rarely, but this seems to be a reasonable way to use it:
structure CountToTenStream where
    i : UInt32 := 0

instance : Stream CountToTenStream UInt32 where
  next? self :=
    if self.i < 10 then
      let i := self.i + 1
      some (i, { i })
    else
      none

def main : IO Unit := do
  for x in ({} : CountToTenStream) do
    IO.println s!"{x}"


My question was about how to translate associated types from Rust to Lean but I guess the example I chose was a bit unfortunate because such a type class already exists in the standard library of both Rust and Lean.
